# CKEditor dialogs: referencing input fields by ID

Tags: dialog, ckeditor

Each input field in the CKEditor dialogs are renamed with a unique number, but the number changes depending on what options are visible.

I need to reference 'txtUrl' which has an id something like #35_textInput.

So far I have discovered that something like this should work:

```
alert(CKEDITOR.instances.myElement.document.$.body.getId('txtUrl'));
```

But it doesn't. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Rio, your solution was really close! This was the final solution:

```
var dialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();
dialog.setValueof('info','txtUrl',"http://google.com");
return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var dialog = this.getDialog();
var elem = dialog.getContentElement('info','txtUrl');
```

Comment: Hi Rio, thanks so much for replying and sorry for the delay.

I have tried the following but the dialog fails to load (no error message in FireBug either)...

CKEDITOR.dialog.add('link', function (a) {
    var b = function () {
        var s = this.getDialog(),
  z = s.getContentElement('info', 'txtUrl');
  z.setValue('asdasd');

If you are able to help I would be eternally grateful and more than happy to make a donation to a charity of your choice!

Regards, R

Answer (score 0):

within an onchange part of an element I now use

```
dialog = this.getDialog();  
alert(dialog.getContentElement('info', 'grootte').getInputElement().$.id);
```

and it gives 'cke_117_select' as a result. (It's a selectbox)

```
alert(dialog.getContentElement('info', 'txtUrl').getInputElement().$.id);
```

gives 'cke_107_textInput'.
I think this is what you (or other visitors to this page) are looking for.

`SetValueOf` still doesn't provide the id, which you may need if you want to do more than fill a text field with a certain text.