# Referencing text input fields in CKEditor dialogs

Tags: reference, ckeditor, field

I've been playing around with this for a couple of weeks now with no success...

In a CKEditor dialog, text input fields are renamed with a unique number - e.g. id: 'txtUrl' will become something like id='27_textinput'.

How do I reference this?

```
// I feel it should be something like:

var myfield = CKEDITOR.instances.myElement.document.$.body.getId('txtUrl');

// or maybe:

var myfield = CKEDITOR.dialog.getContentElement('info','txtUrl');

// and then:

myfield.value = 'myvalue';
```

But these don't work. Please help! Thanks in advance, R

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777286/ckeditor-dialogs-referencing-input-fields-by-id/5053517#5053517

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was the final solution:

```
var dialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();
dialog.setValueOf('info','txtUrl',"http://google.com");
return false;
```

Answer (score 3):

within an onchange part of an element I now use

```
dialog = this.getDialog();  
alert(dialog.getContentElement('info', 'grootte').getInputElement().$.id);
```

and it gives 'cke_117_select' as a result. (It's a selectbox)

```
alert(dialog.getContentElement('info', 'txtUrl').getInputElement().$.id);
```

gives 'cke_107_textInput'.
I think this is what you (or other visitors to this page) are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You have a page containing the CKEditor 3 and a dialog pop up. You open from this dialog, another pop up window, that is a JSP page. In order to set a value to a field in the dialog of CKEditor's parent window, you do the following:

```
window.opener.CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().getContentElement('dialogTabId', 'dialogTabFieldId').setValue('yourValue');
```

This applies to CKEditor 3.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the api dialog sample:

```
    // Get a reference to the "Link Info" tab.
    var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );

    // Set the default value for the URL field.
    var urlField = infoTab.get( 'url' );
    urlField['default'] = 'www.example.com';
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I only just saw this!

I tried the following under onLoad as per your instructions...

var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );
var urlField = infoTab.get( 'txtUrl' );

And then I wanted to set the value onLoad so did the below, but it doesn't work.

urlField.setValue = 'www.example.com';

Hope you can help!

Answer (score -1):

get

```
var ckValue = CKEDITOR.instances['txtUrl'].getData();
```

and set

```
CKEDITOR.instances['txtUrl'].setData(ckValue);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the speedy response! I'm getting "CKEDITOR.instances.txturl is undefined" in FireBug.

The instance has the 'name content_main' so I also tried:

CKEDITOR.instances.content_main['txt_url'].setData('Hello world');

But that throws the same error. An ideas?