# CKEditor: Text box in link dialog

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to interact with a text box in the Link dialog (get the value and set the value). Started with what's already there but it's not working...

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('link', function (a)
{ 
    var b = function () 
    {
         var s = this.getDialog(),
         z = s.getContentElement('info', 'txtUrl');
         z.setValue('asdasd');
    });
});
```

Any ideas will be helpful as I'm sure I'm almost there!

R

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777286/ckeditor-dialogs-referencing-input-fields-by-id/5053517#5053517

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the final solution:

`var dialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();
dialog.setValueof('info','txtUrl','http://google.com');
return false;`

Happy days! Thanks for your help,

R